# How to avoid following download links in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to avoid downloading anything that is a downloadable file when doing a generic Scrapy site crawling.

The problem is that sometimes the links do not "tell" what's behind them and you might end up following a download link.

How can I avoid that? (Detect size, mime-type, etc)

Comment: The way to get the mime type etc   is to write a short js code which uses "fetch" and read the headers. Scrapy has provision to run your js code.

Comment: The only reliable way would be to use the https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#bytes-received signal to inspect the first few bytes of responses and cancel them before they finish if they are undesired based on the content.